# Question of the proof first variation of arc length

Tags: differential-geometry

I have a question on the **Lemma 4.1**, (First variation of arc length formlula) Here is the  [PDF](http://www.mathweb.zju.edu.cn:8080/swm/RG_Section_4.pdf) I am reading.

**Notation**

- $\alpha : [a,b] \times (-\epsilon,\epsilon) \to M^n $, $\alpha(t,s):= \gamma_s(t)$
- **[tangent vector field]**   $T:= \alpha_{*} (\frac{\partial}{\partial t})$
- **[the variation vector field]**  $V:= \alpha_{*} (\frac{\partial}{\partial s})$
- **[The length of $\gamma_s$]**   $L(\gamma_s):= \int_{a}^{b} |T(\gamma_s(t))|dt$

> **Lemma4.1** (First variation of arc length) If $\gamma_{0}$ is parametrized by arc length, that is $|T(\gamma_{0} (t))|\equiv 1 $,
> then,
>
> $$\left.\frac{d}{ds}\right|_{s=0} L(\gamma_s) = -\int _{a}^{b} \left<V, \triangledown_TT\right>dt + \left<V,T\right>|_{a}^{b}  $$

This image is a proof of the **Lemma 4.1**

[image]

My the question is **why the first and second equality hold** within the proof.

**[First equality]**
observe  $\frac{d}{ds}\left|T(\gamma_s(t))\right|$ Since this is composition map. Furthermore, this arc length is parametrized by unit vectors,

$$\frac{d}{ds}\left|(T \circ \gamma_s)(t)\right|=  \left|T'(\gamma_s(t))\right|\left|\frac{\partial}{\partial s} \gamma(t,s)\right| =  \left|V(\gamma_s(t))\right|\left|\frac{\partial}{\partial s} \gamma(t,s)\right| \quad   ... \quad (1)$$

Then, substituting $s=0$ into $(1)$, However, I do not know why the equality

$$\left.\frac{d}{ds}\right|_{s=0} L(\gamma_s) \overset{??}{=} \frac{1}{2} \int_{a}^{b} |T|^{-1} V\left<T,T\right> $$ Or,

$$\frac{d}{ds}\left|(T \circ \gamma_s)(t)\right| \overset{??}{=} \frac{1}{2}|T|^{-1} V\left<T,T\right> $$

holds... To begin with, since, $|T|\equiv 1$, clearly, $|T|^{-1}(=1/|T|)\equiv 1$ and $|T|^2 = \left<T,T\right>  \equiv  1$. Moreover, since $T'=V$, $V$ need to be alive. However, I do not understand where $\frac{1}{2}$ comes from. This means that $|\frac{\partial}{\partial s} \gamma(t,s)|$ need to be  $1/2 $. But it is significantly illogical.

**[Second equality - Edited]**
And next, I cannot **certainly** understand why,

$$ \frac{1}{2} \int_{a}^{b} |T|^{-1} V\left<T, T\right> \overset{??}{=} \int_{a}^{b} |T|^{-1} \left<T,\triangledown_V T\right> \quad ... \quad (2) $$

My thought is here :  If I see $V$ as on (differential) operator, then
$$V\left<T,T\right>= \left<\triangledown_V T, T\right> + \left<T, \triangledown_V T\right> = 2 \left<T, \triangledown_V T\right>  $$. Or equivalently,
$$ \left<T, \triangledown_V T\right>= \frac{1}{2}V\left<T,T\right> $$

Hence, $(2)$ holds, is it right idea?

Comment: Isn't $\langle\cdot,\cdot\rangle$ symmetric? And is this the Levi-Civita connection? What does that tell you?

Comment: I am now finding out that  $<\triangledown_V T, T>$, $<T, \triangledown_V T>$   are "symmetric" I misunderstood that these are not symmetric.